# How to increase significant digits in Mathematica

Tags: output-formatting, machine-precision

How can I increase the number of significant digits in Mathematica?
When I import a matrix, an element like 112.5276 is rounded to 112.528. I would like to increase the number of significant digits globally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is rounded internally. It is just the default setting for number display is 6-digits. You can change that default in the Preferences panel. Select the Numbers and Formatting tabs in the Appearance panel. Use the Displayed Precision edit field.

[image: prefs]