# Setting value of number on certain decimal points

Tags: mathematical-optimization

How do I fix number on certain decimal point? For example number 10304,390456 should be 10304,39. I tried `NumberPoints`, `Nest`, and so on, but nothing worked. What is the right command to do it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but maybe `Round[10304.390456, .01]`

Comment: Greetings! To make the most of Mma.SE please **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned. Why not choosing a meaningful name?

Comment: I think you find what you are looking in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54602/3066)

Comment: If you want to change the number, Jason's answer is a good way to go. If you merely want to modify how it is displayed you can use `NumberForm[10304.390456, {7, 2}]` which yields 10304.39. Note that the output is **not** a number and you wouldn't want to use it in downstream calculations.

Answer (score 2):

Note that commas have a specific meaning in *Mathematica* syntax, and "." is normally used to mark the decimal. Another useful syntax detail to be aware of is "`" ([NumberMarks](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberMarks.html)), used to indicate the type and [precision of numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html).

The literal answer to your question is the solution suggested by @JasonB:

```
Round[10304.390456, 0.01]//FullForm
(*10304.39`*)
Precision@%
(*MachinePrecision*)
```

which rounds your number to the nearest multiple of 0.01, and returns a machine precision real. Equivalently, you can do:

```
Round[100 x]/100.]//FullForm
(*10304.39`*)
```

Just for display purposes, you can use `NumberForm`, as @JackLaVigne mentioned:

```
NumberForm[10304.390456, {7, 2}, NumberPoint -> ","]
(*10304,39*)
```

but keep in mind that this isn't intended for downstream calculations, and can lead to expressions that don't simplify without special help:

```
NumberForm[Round[10304.390456, 0.01], {7, 2}, NumberPoint -> ","] + 1.01
(*1.01 + 10304,39*)
```